# lxml.html set error "TypeError: Argument must be bytes or unicode, got 'NoneType' "

Tags: python, lxml, lxml.html

I am trying to put a 'defer' attribute into script tags using lxml.html but I get the error

TypeError: Argument must be bytes or unicode, got 'NoneType'

or

TypeError: set() takes exactly 2 positional arguments (1 given)

if I use

```
script.set('defer')
```

According to http://lxml.de/lxmlhtml.html

.set(key, value=None):
Sets an HTML attribute. If no value is given, or if the value is None, it creates a boolean attribute like

```
<form novalidate></form>
```

or

```
<div custom-attribute></div>.
```

my code is

```
import lxml.html  

htmldoc = lxml.html.parse( file )   
headElement = htmldoc.find("head")
listOfScripts = headElement.xpath("script")

if len(listOfScripts) > 0:
    for script in listOfScripts:
        script.set('defer', value=None)
```

Comment: hmm, may be it's bug in lxml. Documentation says that `None` (or if it is omitting) means set as boolean attribute. But IMHO you can set it to "defer" string value, XHTML should eats it too

Answer (score 0):

The documentation you linked is for the latest version of `lxml`, the feature about `.set()` that you’re talking about was added in version 3.7, your version however, is < 3.7

View the changelog [here](http://lxml.de/3.8/changes-3.8.0.html):

> 3.7.0 (2016-12-10)
>
> **Features added**
>
> • GH#201: Calling the method `.set('attrname')` without value argument (or None) on HTML elements
>   creates an attribute without value that serialises like  attrname>. Patch by Daniel Holth.

Comment: Yes my version is 3.6 Thank you

Comment: I have updated my lxml to version 3.8.0.0 and while it now runs without an error, script.set('defer') or script.set('defer', None) or script.set('defer', value=None) all result in <script src="..". defer=""> being put in my file rather than <script src="..". defer>

Comment: “*In XML, attributes must have at least the empty string as their value like `<form novalidate=""></form>`*” please read the doc, it says that it can be empty only for HTML files, and will keep an empty string if it’s XML.